# dnn - upload an image to portal and use it in html module?

Tags: dotnetnuke

how do i upload an image to the portal and use it in my html of my html module?

i have an html module i want to use and part of it is an image. how do i upload to my portal and then reference the url where it is on my server inside my html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you didn't see my comments on the other one. One way is to just find the file on the hard drive and figure out the link manually in relation to your web root. But if you are using this as a portal system then this might not be the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is also upload option right withing html editor. click on image manager icon and it will give you the option to upload an image.
[alt text http://images.devs-on.net/Image/rw5tTdgNRgs22f1-MyWebsiteHomeAlp.png](http://images.devs-on.net/Image/rw5tTdgNRgs22f1-MyWebsiteHomeAlp.png)
[alt text http://images.devs-on.net/Image/YjlGTN1GTUVMR1p-MyWebsiteHomeAlp.png](http://images.devs-on.net/Image/YjlGTN1GTUVMR1p-MyWebsiteHomeAlp.png)

Answer (score 0):

If your HTML is being put in the DNN HTML module, you could also use the media picker baked in.

If you want a more integrated option, you could use the DNN FileManager API to accomplish integrated uploading and retrieving of files. The DNNFilePickerUploader might come in handy for this, which will give you a DNN file ID which you could the use to get the image url.